# Redirect careers.stackexchange to careers.stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs, stackexchange.com

I found myself going to http://careers.stackexchange.com/ when meaning to go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ several times.

Now it might be just me, but I think it would be nice if careers.stackexchange would redirect to careers.stackoverflow or at least contain a 'did you mean?' bit.

Comment: The advantage of the link is that you'd still have the panda.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this would be a bit misleading, considering that the Careers site is *only* for programming jobs and is tightly integrated with Stack Overflow. There are [lots of sites on the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), but only one or two of them deal with computer programming.

In fact, if I saw a link to http://careers.stackexchange.com/, I would assume that was a way to see job openings available at Stack Exchange and begin the process of applying for one of them.

A <strike>suggestive</strike> suggestion link on the current page might be acceptable, but an outright redirect seems wrong to me.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that a suggestion would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Ah, you want a new job?